# Showing a data list in a multi selection pop up menu

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

Whats up guys! I want to show a list of data that come from SQLite on the screen over a button. I would like to do as a pop up menu. However it needs to be a multi selection one. After, this data should be inserted in a Recycler View. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Yes you are right with the idea. Now, you are just remaining with the syntax...!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use AlertDialog then inflate your own view and set the inflated view using setView() method.